# Design pattern required - Facade to multiple interchangable libraries

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a 3rd party library i am interfacing with using a facade pattern.  Now, i have a further requirement that the 3rd party library can be changed easily (not at runtime) thus the facade have needs to be able to handle this.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest creating `Facade` that needs to be an interface (or abstract class, whichever language do you use) with several implementations. Each implementation is a concrete facade wrapping 3rd party library:

[image: UML diagram]

<sup>Powered by [yuml.me](http://yuml.me/)</sup>

Comment: Nice presentation, do you mind me asking how you made the graphic?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz - where in this design would you see the switch for deciding which facade to use?  There is one client which can use any of these facades.  Would you expect to see some sort of factory method in the client or would it be as simple as using a class constant to define which faced should be used or a config value held in xml file etc?

Comment: @user1189880: all your suggestions are valid. You can use a factory, configuration option, XML configuration. If you are using any kind of [tag:dependency-injection] than this is a typical case. Technically you can even switch facades at runtime.